# Send message when someone joins to the specific channel - Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a Discord bot for sending a message when someone joins a specific channel, but it also sends a message when the user mutes their microphone. What's wrong?

You can find my current code below:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
    let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;

    const channel2 = client.channels.cache.get('channelid here');
 
    if(newUserChannel === "channelid here")
    { 
        // User Joins a voice channel
        channel2.send("message");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check if there was a change in the channels, so check that the `newMember.channelID` is not the same as the `oldMember.channelID`:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.channelID;
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.channelID;

  const channel2 = client.channels.cache.get('channelid here');

  if (
    newUserChannel !== oldUserChannel &&
    newUserChannel === 'channelid here'
  ) {
    // User Joins a voice channel
    channel2.send('message');
  }
});
```